# How to set range for int in sql server

Tags: sql-server, range

hey I'm new in SQL server i was wondering if we can set range to int (when creating table)
like we set range to char

```
testing char(5) not null
```

when i tried to use the same way to set range in int

```
testing int(5) not null
```

it will get error, so how to set range for int. if can't can you tell me why?

Comment: An `int` is an `int` is an `int` - you cannot specify a length for an `int`. If you need to limit its range of valid numbers, you need to use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on the column

Comment: There is no range for numbers like there is for strings.  If you want to use smaller number you can save space by using tinyint. [Microsoft Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: What kind of "range" are you looking for? An allowable range of values (min/max), or a size (tinyint, int, bigint - number of bytes required to store the value)?

Comment: For the sake of the example, if `int(5)` did work, what would the expected range be?  For example, 5 digits or perhaps a maximum value of 5. And are negative numbers included in your range. If we knew what you're desired goal was or problem is, perhaps someone would have a suggestion.

Comment: the range i mean is it size
so int(5) mean 5 digits

Comment: For that use decimal(5, 0)

Comment: I can't stand it when people down-vote questions just because they come from people who have yet to gain a substantial knowledge on a topic.  Did this question show a lack of research effort?  Was it unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 12):

There is no INT(5) data type in sql server , but you can make use of CHECK constraints to put a limit/Range on values that can be inserted in that column.

Google to learn more about Check Constraint and you would do something like this.....

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Testing  INT CHECK (testing > 100 AND testing <500)
  , OtherCol INT 
);
```

Comment: Here is the Microsoft technical documentation on Check Constraints:
 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints